# Switching from pq to sqlite3 ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite

I'm getting error after trying to change from a pg to sqlite3.

```
rake db:reset
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Gem::LoadError: pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:175:in `spec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:reset => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Now I know that activeRecord is telling me to add the PG gem but my machine is having error running the pq server (rather then being productive and fixing it, I'm being lazy by trying to put sqlite on deve and keeping pg on product)

Any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to change `adapter` in `config/database.yml` from `postgresql` to `sqlite3`.

It should help.

Comment: Perfect, Worked like a charm. Thank you :)                                                      I'll accept the answer when I can